# Azure Data Factory : Acquire MI token from MI store V1 failed. Error code 2403

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I got error below from Azure Data Factory while i try to make changes on Azure Blob Storage:

```
Get access token from MSI failed for Datafactory. Please verify resource url is valid and retry. Details: Accquire MI token from MI store V1 failed.
Failure type: User configuration issue
Error Code: 2403
```

My resource url is: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subsId/resourceGroups/$rgname/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$adfName?api-version=2018-06-01

I am using Web Activity in ADF to access Blob Storage using managed identity which is create during creation of the ADF instance.

When i use SAS token to access to Blob Storage, it works fine.

I check the error code 2403 from web but i couldn't find anything.

Do you have any idea why it fails with Managed Identity as a method of authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We solved this issue by assigning "Storage Blob Data Owner" Role for the Storage account on the Azure Data Factory managed Identity.
2. By setting the Authentication URL for MSI as "https://storage.azure.com"